# Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I was trying to update my version of bootstrap from 3.1.0 to the currently latests 3.3.0.
But I noticed after upgrading that my dropdown menu's aren't working anymore.
For some reason the javascript doesn't pickup the elements with the `.dropdown-toggle` css class.

But when I dive into the chrome javascript console and execute the following command:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

I notice the dropdown menu's do work. I compared the html of the menu's before and after this command and it remained the same.

I also looked in the release notes from bootstrap and could find any breaking changes regarding dropdown menus. This is a example piece of my code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Customers</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/company">Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/company/customer_form">Customer form</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Does anybody got a tip?

Comment: any error from console?

Comment: @fsi no errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

Worked just fine, only thing you must do is to use Jquery latest
Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2qWy8/22/

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```